Authenticator does not support the request when trying to access the user cart " user not found "
I am working with symfony 6 as a backend and reactjs as frontend , I have an api that fetches the contents of the cart of each user  but it's throwing an error whenever i try to access my cart from the frontend interface {message: "User not  found"} along with this in the symfony terminal :
[Application] Jun 10 16:14:34 |DEBUG  | SECURI Checking for authenticator support. authenticators=2 firewall_name="main"
[Application] Jun 10 16:14:34 |DEBUG  | SECURI Checking support on authenticator. authenticator="App\\Security\\UsersAuthenticator"
[Application] Jun 10 16:14:34 |DEBUG  | SECURI Authenticator does not support the request.
[Application] Jun 10 16:14:34 |DEBUG  | SECURI Checking support on authenticator. authenticator="Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Http\\Authenticator\\JsonLoginAuthenticator"
[Application] Jun 10 16:14:34 |DEBUG  | SECURI Authenticator does not support the request

however when I login to my application the user gets authenticated correctly , and when i test the cart api request on postman  ( /api/panier/get ) it also works correctly
so again the problem only occurs when I access the /api/get/panier  in my interface  so heres both backend and frontend of this request :

#[Route('/api/panier', name: 'panier')]

class PanierController extends AbstractController
{
   

    #[Route('/get', name: 'get-panier', methods: ['GET','POST'])]

    public function getPanierContents(  #[CurrentUser] ?Users $user , Request $request ): Response
    {
        
    if (!$user) {
        error_log("User not found"); 
        return $this->json(['message' => 'User not  found'], Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
    }

    // If user is found, log user details
    error_log("User found: " . $user->getUserIdentifier());

        $panier = $user->getPanier();

        if (!$panier) {
            return $this->json(['message' => 'Panier not found'], Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
        }

        $billets = $panier->getBillets();

        // Convert billets collection to array
        $billetsArray = [];
        foreach ($billets as $billet) {
            $billetsArray[] = [
                'id' => $billet->getId(),
                'date_debut_evenement'=>$billet->getDateDebutEvenement(),
                // Add other properties you want to include
            ];
        }
    //    $serializedContents = $serializer->serialize($contents, 'json', ['groups' => 'billet']);

        return $this->json($billetsArray);
    

}

function getToken() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    console.log("Retrieved token:", token); // Add this line for debugging
    return token;    
}
export const fetchPanierData = (userId) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        
        const token = getToken();
        if (!token) {
            throw new Error("No token found");
        }
        const response = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/api/panier/get`, {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
                
            },
  
      });
      dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_PANIER_SUCCESS', payload: response.data });
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_PANIER_FAILURE', payload: error.response ? error.response.data : error.message });
    }
  };
};


for more insights here's my login api logic :
   #[Route('/api/login', name: 'api_login', methods: ['POST',"GET"])]
  public function index(#[CurrentUser] ?Users $user , JWTTokenManagerInterface $jwtManager): JsonResponse
      {
         if (null === $user) {
             return $this->json([
                 'message' => 'missing credentials',
             ], Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
         }

      $token = $jwtManager->create($user);
      
$data=[
    'id'=> $user->getId(),
    'user'  => $user->getUserIdentifier(),
    'username'=> $user->getUsername(),
    'role'=>$user->getRoles(),
    'token' => $token,
];
        
          return new JsonResponse($data, Response::HTTP_OK);

      }

and here's my security.yaml :
 firewalls:
    dev:
      pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
      security: false
    main:
      lazy: true
      provider: app_user_provider
      custom_authenticator: App\Security\UsersAuthenticator
      logout:
        path: app_logout
        target: connexion_page
      

      json_login:
        check_path: api_login
     api:
      pattern: ^/api/
      stateless: true
      jwt: ~


Thank you in advance
the token is being retrived correctly and I couldn't find the issue cause it's working fine on postman so is it a security configuration or what
